# .NET Software running on x64 but compiled on x86 for Any CPU (VS2008)

Tags: .net-3.5, x86, 64-bit, anycpu

I have a problem, whereby I’m getting runtime errors with a compiled program.  This works fine in the development environment (x86), but not on the production environment (which is x64).

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/5ad0ff2c-558c-43ba-a59d-9cd0a0785103) article, which seems to imply that compiling the software as Any CPU may run the software as x64 software if it’s run in a 64 bit environment.

Is this the case, and if so, should software ever be compiled under Any CPU (as it seems to make for a mismatch between the two environments)?

Comment: It entirely depends on what you're doing. It's hard to give you advice without knowing what the environment is or what errors you're getting.

Comment: The errors are inconsistent, and range from the program freezing to memory access errors.

Comment: Windows on Windows for X64... not sure if that is used by .NET engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AnyCPU is great if you are using managed code only. Managed code can be executed in a 32-bit-process or 64-bit-process. With AnyCPU, the framework chooses the bitness native to the OS.

The same is not true for unmanaged code. It needs to be compiled either as 32-bit or 64-bit code. Of course, due to the WoW64 subsystem, 64-bit Windows can run 64-bit processes.

**But 64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit modules (DLLs, OCXs, etc.).**

That means if your program is using unmanaged modules of some kind, better make sure to set the bitness manually so that all components have the same bitness.